# VBA IE 10 Automation - Automatically Save PDFs

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-10, browser-automation

I'm trying to automate the process of saving `PDF` invoices for bookkeeping purposes. The method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306915/vba-ie-how-to-get-past-file-save-prompt) does not work because a login is required to access the invoices.

I currently have a macro that navigates to the page, logs in and opens the links to each invoice. The `URL` scheme for these invoices is `.../account/invoice/?invoice_number=XXXXXX`. Navigating to each of these `URL` brings up the files in the

[image: View Downloads]

window. I would like the files to automatically save, but according to [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/how-can-i-disable-the-open-or-save-prompt-when-i/e490416d-7cb5-4661-9e9d-4881872ed29d), the `Always ask before opening this type of file` option was depreciated from IE 10 and 11 due to security reasons.

I attempted to automatically click `Save` using [this method](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/567033-automate-file-download-dialog-box-without-sendkeys.html), but the code here seems to be for a different version of IE.

The line:

```
hWnd = FindWindow("#32770", "File Download")
```

was modified to:

```
hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "View Downloads - Windows Internet Explorer")
```

This successfully captures the download window, but it fails to find the `&Save` button for me to click. My guess would be that it's because there are multiple save buttons.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to download with the imported URLDownloadToFile but beware about properly compiler #def'ing 64bit vs 32 bit on 64 bit.

Comment: Install Acrobat Reader or similar and have it setup to open PDF links inside the browser. Then search thru the IE cache file.

Comment: @PatricK This seems to be the way to go. I can see the files appear in the temporary files directory. However, FileSystemObject only sees counters.dat and desktop.ini in the temporary internet files folder.

Comment: Recursively look thru all folders from `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.IE5"` should get you going, and perhaps add condition to only consider files that are 1 or 2 days old.

Comment: @ PatricK That did the trick! I used the code from the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba) to do a recursive search.